# In a circle of diameter $n^{3/4}$, inscribe $n$ equal height trapeziums. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\text{Area of circle}-\text{Area of trapeziums})$.

Tags: geometry, limits, circles

In a circle of diameter $n^{3/4}$, inscribe $n$ equal height trapeziums. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\text{Area of circle}-\text{Area of trapeziums})$.

The trapeziums are inscribed like this:
[image]
(The top and bottom trapeziums are degenerate, so they are also triangles.)

I worked out, by playing with desmos, that the limit converges if the diameter is related to $n$ as described.

The limit expression (for even $n$), after simplification, is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}-1-2\sum_{k=1}^\frac{n}{2}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2k}{n}\right)^2}\right)$$

(Actually, I have shown that the limit is $\frac{5}{6}$, in an indirect way: I calculated the limit of the areas of the four largest circular segments, then calculated the limit of the areas of the other circular segments using the [asymptotic error estimate for the trapezium rule](https://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Ewhan/3800.d/S5-2.pdf), and added them together. But I would like to evaluate the limit *without* using the asymptotic error estimate for the trapezium rule, because my high school students have not learned it, and also because I'm curious to see other ways to evaluate the limit.)